# C post increment not working on a pointer but addition assignment does

Tags: c

I have a simple function to count words and characters taking two pointers and the file stream:

```
void countWordsAndChars(FILE *stream, int *pWordCount, int *pCharCount)
{
    int ch = getc(stream);
    while (ch != EOF)
    {
        if (!isspace(ch) && ch != '\n')
        {
            *pCharCount++; // Does not work
            *pCharCount += 1; // Works
        }
        else 
        {
            *pWordCount++; // Does not work
            *pWordCount += 1; // Works
        }
        ch = getc(stream);
    }
}
```

If I use the autoincrement operators (`*pWordCount++`) it doesnt work. But if I use the addition assignment (`*pWordCount += 1`) it does.

I'm coming from the web dev world and am pretty new to C. Please explain why.

Thanks.

Comment: @PaulHankin no, it dereferences the pointer, then increases the pointer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are different:

`*pCharCount++;` equals to `*(pCharCount++)` so it dereferences the pointer (which does not do anything) and then increases the pointer.

`*pCharCount += 1;` increases the object referenced by the pointer.

If you want to use postincrement operator you need to: `(*pCharCount)++;`

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer should become clear by looking at the [table of operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

As you can see in the table, the `++` postfix operator has higher priority than the indirection operator `*`. (Please do not confuse the postfix `++` operator with the prefix `++` operator, as they have different priorities.)

Therefore, the expression

```
*pCharCount++
```

is equivalent to:

```
*(pCharCount++)
```

On the other hand, the `*` operator has higher priority than the `+=` operator, so the expression

```
*pCharCount += 1
```

is equivalent to:

```
(*pCharCount) += 1
```